Unable to Write DataFrame to File in Python, No Error Message
I'm trying to write data from a DataFrame (oracle_df) to a file in Python. Despite no apparent errors, the file remains empty. Below is my code:
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
local_filename=  local_path+file_name+"_"+current_date+".csv" 
try: 
    if not os.path.exists(local_filename):
    open(local_filename, 'a').close()   
    with open(local_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write("Data from Oracle\n")
        output_file.write(','.join(oracle_df.columns) + '\n')
        oracle_df_string = oracle_df.rdd.map(lambda row: ','.join(map(str, row))).collect()
        output_file.write('\n'.join(oracle_df_string))
        output_file.write("\n==============================\n")
        output_file.write("Data from Hive\n")
        output_file.write(','.join(hive_df.columns) + '\n')
        hive_df_string = hive_df.rdd.map(lambda row: ','.join(map(str, row))).collect()
        hive_df.write('\n'.join(hive_df_string))
        hive_df.write("\n==============================\n")
        output_file.close()
        print("Data successfully written to file :",local_filename)
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)

# Debug prints
    print("Oracle DataFrame:")
    oracle_df.show()
    print("oracle_df.columns values",oracle_df.columns)
    print("oracle_df_string",oracle_df_string)

I've ensured that oracle_df contains data by printing it to the console. However, when writing to the file, no data appears. I've also tried manually creating the file, but to no avail.
There are no error messages or exceptions thrown during execution. Could someone help identify why the file remains empty despite the DataFrame containing data? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Any reason you're not using oracle_df.to_csv(output_file)?

I need to append Multiple df output with print message in same output_file, so thought u use write and join lines . @Barmar

You can do that with to_csv(). Use header=False so you won't get multiple header lines.

But I'm not sure why it's not working as you've written. What does print(oracle_df_string) show?

BTW, you don't need output_file.close(). This is done automatically by with

but before writing 2nd df output , i need to give message also like output_file.write("Data from Oracle\n")/output_file.write("Data from hive\n")/ etc.
is it possible to do this with to_csv . kindly suggest.

Yes, it's possible. If you give it an open file object, it will just append to whatever you've already written.

oracle_df_string = oracle_df.rdd.map(lambda row: ','.join(map(str, row))).collect()
It shows the rows of datafrme

Please help/guide me to modify this existing one. @Barmar

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
